# CDContext crash before app is launched

Tags: ios, crash, cgcontext

I have an issue since yesterday: my app doesn't open anymore.
In fact yes, it opens, but it stays locked on the launchscreen, and I get some issues on the console even before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called:

> Oct 14 12:17:20  Cash[334] : CGContextSaveGState: invalid
>   context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set
>   CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>
> Oct 14 12:17:20  Cash[334] : CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid
>   context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set
>   CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>
> Oct 14 12:17:20  Cash[334] : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid
>   context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set
>   CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

What happens??

I think the app is running fine, given that the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method gets executed until the end (and my Core Data stack is loaded, etc...), this is just the screen that is freezed so I can't do nothing (and nothing happens when I click on the Home button of my iPhone...).

What is this bug ?

I'm running my app on an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.0.2
(I don't have this issue on the iPhone simulator... and I didn't have it until yesterday!!)

Please help me :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I finally resolved my issue, it was an infinite while looping which locked the app (in a class faaaaaaar away). Spent hours searching for...

Meanwhile, I still have the CGContext warnings at the launch..